# How to allow an image to extend beyond a Form {} in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, forms, image, swiftui

I'm looking to have an image extend above a form, as pictured in the first attached screenshot below. My code below accomplishes this when I run it on the Simulator using a iPod touch (7th Generation), but produces the second screenshot when I run it on iPhone 12 and iPhone 13. Any advice about how to ensure that the image extends beyond the limits of the form as intended on all devices?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .offset(y: -50)
                .padding(.bottom, -50)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form` uses different styles on different devices. A possible solution is to use instead `List` with explicit style for all devices.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
    List {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .offset(y: -50)
            .padding(.bottom, -50)
    }
    .listStyle(.grouped)   // << here !!
```